# Cooperating eventlet with system calls

Tags: python, eventlet

My project uses `eventlet` and now I have to asynchronously read and write to a file(a device, actually). I tried `eventlet.tpool.execute()` to run the reading thread, but it blocks the main loop.

My question is, how to run the reading thread concurrently with the eventlet thread? Is it possible for these two threads to communicate in some ways?

A quick sketch:

```
def functionB():
  while True:
    data = readFile()
    doSomethingWith(data)

def functionA():
  doSomething()
  tpool.execute(functionB)
  doSomethingElse()
```

Then `doSomethingElse()` is never called.

Comment: Could you provide more details on "blocks the main loop" part? Also, minimal reproduction code would be very helpful.

Comment: @temoto Added a quick sketch, hope you would understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`tpool.execute` is not supposed to return until `functionB` ended. Yours does not end, so `doSomethingElse()` is not supposed to execute.

In other words, `tpool.execute` is not fire-and-forget type. It spawns function in OS thread *and* synchronizes caller. Which is very useful, actually.

If you want to start a new forever working thread, just do it with normal Python `threading.Thread`.

Typical use case for `tpool.execute`:

```
def main():
  f = tpool.execute(open, ...)
  while True:
    chunk = tpool.execute(f.read, size)
    # process chunk
  tpool.execute(f.close)
```

You may try the following code to fix your problem:

```
def functionB():
  while True:
    data = tpool.execute(readFile)  # just readFile -> tpool.execute
    doSomethingWith(data)

def functionA():
  doSomething()
  eventlet.spawn_n(functionB)  # tpool.execute -> spawn_n
  doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: Exactly, but does `tpool` suppose to be a pool of threads? So what should I do to make the `tpool.execute()` NOT block succeeding calls?

Comment: Pool part means that there are few threads available to do work concurrently, that is, you may run `tpool.execute` from multiple green threads and they will execute at most N (pool size) concurrent jobs. Pool has two key properties: reuse previously initialized resource and limit number of resources to create. In this context, resource is an OS thread.

Comment: If you want to execute one thing in background, you don't need thread pool. Just start `threading.Thread` (assuming you did not monkey patch threading).

Comment: That's the problem. The main thread is a thread spawned by eventlet, and I cannot control that part.